# Fazer nome da guia igual ao conteúdo de uma célula no Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

Como faço para colocar o nome da guia igual ao conteúdo de uma célula? Por exemplo, se conteúdo da célula `A1` for `01`, o nome da guia é `01` também.

Comment: Se estiver criando uma planilha dinamicamente isso é fácil mas depende do componente que você utilizar.
Apenas pelo arquivo do Excel não dá. O nome da aba não aceita fórmulas.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Você vai precisar usar VBA pra fazer o que quer.

A minha primeira tentativa foi criar uma função que você pudesse usar diretamente na fórmula. Mas isso não funcionou (simplesmente não atualizava a propriedade `Name` da aba, provavelmente porque o Excel estava calculando fórmulas naquele momento).

A segunda tentativa funcionou, baseada no evento de alteração da seleção de células na planilha. Basta abrir o editor do VBA e digitar o seguinte código:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Excel.Range)
    Set Target = Range("A1")
    If Target = "" Then Exit Sub
    On Error GoTo Badname
    ActiveSheet.Name = Left(Target, 31)
    Exit Sub
Badname:
    MsgBox "Por favor, revise o nome na célula A1." & Chr(13) _
    & "Parece que ele contém um ou mais caracteres ilegais." & Chr(13)
    Range("A1").Activate
End Sub
```

Note que esse código presume que o usuário estará digitando o valor dessa célula, e por isso exibe uma mensagem de erro no caso de problemas na atualização do nome da aba. Se a sua célula tiver atualização automática (de outra origem que não seja o usuário), você provavelmente vai querer remover essa exibição de mensagem e substitui-la por um tratamento automatizado (talvez definir um título padrão, por exemplo).

Não esqueça de salvar a sua planilha habilitada para macros (extensão *.xlsm).

P.S.: eu estava pra fazer um código quando achei esse pronto (só traduzi o texto). A fonte é [esse site](http://excel.tips.net/T002145_Dynamic_Worksheet_Tab_Names.html).

Comment: Opa, valeu mesmo, muito obrigado. Funcionou perfeitamente!

Comment: Olá João. Que bom que resolveu. Fico feliz em ajudar. :) Ah, por favor, pense a respeito de aceitar a resposta, se você julgar que foi o caso: http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/1078/como-e-por-que-aceitar-uma-resposta